# Array value not getting populated

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

In this below program user enters the number of city name to be inserted and then a String array is initialized with that size.Then I try to iterate through loop and initialize every index of array with the value(City Name) inserted from user.
But when I tried to print value from array it ask for one less value..What I mean is if i say number of city is 2 ,so my loop should be iterated twice and twice I should insert value but instead i get to insert value only once.
On debugging i realized that the 0th element is getting inialized by itself from somewhere.I am not able to find the exact problem .

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EmptyStringGenerator  {
    public static void main(String []ard)  {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many cities?");

        String[]favoriteCities = new String[scanner.nextInt()];
        for(int i=0;i<favoriteCities.length;i++){
            favoriteCities[i]=scanner.nextLine();

        }

        for(String str:favoriteCities){
            System.out.print(str+" ");
        }

    }
}
```

My Input:

```
2
Delhi
```

Output:

```
Delhi
```

Comment: and what it should be? please add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you read the int with [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29), but don't consume the line end! The rest of the line is left unprocessed, and the next [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) call goes on from that point.

**nextLine() doc**

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

To correct the issue:

```
    String[]favoriteCities = new String[scanner.nextInt()]; //read int

    //consume line end, and do nothing with it
    scanner.nextLine();
    //now read the cities.
    for(int i=0;i<favoriteCities.length;i++){
        favoriteCities[i]=scanner.nextLine();

    }
```

Recommended reading:

- [Scanner Java API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 2):

Line 0 is the end line after "2". `nextInt()` does not read that. Add a dummy `nextLine()` after reading the number.

Comment: @ Anuj Kumar Jha: How you could have debugged this in seconds: Either by walking through the code in a debugger/IDE, or by adding `System.out.println("i = " + i);` inside your loop to see what was happening when.

Answer (score 1):

Use `next()` method instead of `nextLine()`.Since `nextLine()` reads the `new line` skipped by the `nextInt()` method .
[nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped

[next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next)

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner

So the code will be now

```
public static void main(String []ard)  
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many cities?");

    String[]favoriteCities = new String[scanner.nextInt()];
    for(int i=0;i<favoriteCities.length;i++)
    {
        favoriteCities[i]=scanner.next();
    }

    for(String str:favoriteCities)
    {
        System.out.print(str+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the OP `question` correctly, input is `int` and `city name`, and the output should be `number of times (int) the city name`, say e.g `2 Delhi` output `Delhi Delhi`, but he is getting only `Delhi`.

### SOLUTION

```
    String[]favoriteCities = new String[scanner.nextInt()];
    String cityToBeAdded = scanner.next();
    for(int i=0;i<favoriteCities.length;i++){
        favoriteCities[i]=cityToBeAdded;

    }

    for(String str:favoriteCities){
        System.out.print(str+" ");
    }
```